# Get all the Tables with a checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a basic table structure. What im trying to do is grab all of the cells and store them as a js variable before I send them over to my mail function. The purpose is that a user has a list of apartments (table for each), they then select which apartments are suitable and send that list via wp_mail. All the mail side is working but Id like to only send the apartments that are selected.

```
 <table id="list-container" class=>
  <tr>
   <td>

      <table id="list-item" class=>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="selectthis">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="list-item" class=>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="selectthis">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>


  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Im gettin the full list using .html() but I need only the ones containing a checked checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**:checked**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and [**:has()**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('table:has(:checked)')
```

Comment: will that iterate over all the tables?

Comment: @AlexKnopp, yes it will iterate over all the tables then select only the ones that have a checked checkbox

Comment: This is not quite working. With the following var content = jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(:checked)').html(); The apartment-entry-container is the containing div to include the table attr. I am only getting a single table. Or if i select 3 items i am only getting 2. Then only 1 goes through to my ajax function.

Comment: @AlexKnopp, replicate the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net so I can be able to better help

Comment: @AlexKnopp, is it still not working? Did you see the fiddle above?

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you sooner. Ive been off work for a couple of days. This does seem to be working better but its still only getting a single entry when i click send. If i chose more than a single entry i still only get one table in the console.log. Thanks